# <h:selectOneMenu> dropdown list moving upwards in IE11

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-11

I have a  to display a dropdown list. It's behaving differently in IE 11 than other browsers.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{eventConfigBean.selectedData.orgId}" id="orgId" 
                    disabled="#{eventConfigBean.selectedData.disableOrgId}" tabindex="1" 
                            style="width:100%;font-size:11;">                                       
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />                                           
                    <c:forEach var="orgIdList" items="#{eventConfigBean.orgIdVOList}">                      
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{orgIdList.value}" itemValue="#{orgIdList.value}" />                      
                    </c:forEach>
                    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{eventConfigBean.getEventNames}" reRender="eventName" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

First time when I select the item it is working fine,

[image: Screenshot: First time selecting an item:]

But when re selecting, the item list is moving upwards and centering on the selected item.

[image: Screenshot: After Re selecting item list is moving upwards:]

Comment: can u show your code?

Comment: did you try to put ``normalize.css`` in your stylesheet? each browsers has different behaviors

Comment: My colleague sits next to me and we both use IE11 - on the same website, his does this, mine doesn't. Good old Microsoft.

Comment: Any code or preferably a JSFiddle?

Comment: @devpro  Sample code added.

Comment: did u try this? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7, IE=11" />

Comment: @devpro Yes, tried but not working..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem   . found a workaround solution in codepen

```
but it required some extra wrapper div
<div id="box">
 <div id="open"></div>
 <select>
<option>first</option>
<option>second</option>
<option>third</option>
 </select>
  <div id="mark"></div>
<div id="refer"></div>
</div>

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvrbeW?editors=0100
```